# How Would I Search Gmail for Specific Entries from Outside of Gmail?

Tags: gmail, search

I am trying to figure out a way to come up with a tool or a way to search a Gmail account (info@mydomain.com) for bug entries without being logged in to the Gmail account.  Our software generates automatic bug reports for certain errors and sometimes the user submits these without their email address included so it's hard to find which error is associated with which user.

After finding groups of errors, it would also be nice to pull them out and send these errors for to my programmers.  I could rate these errors in order of frequency if I could pull out a list.  I could imagine other ways to organize or otherwise manipulate these data if I could get at them easier.

What tools/scripts would I need to do this?  How might I go about doing this?  Perhaps an export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will likely need to filter these into a label, then use a custom-made tool to process them via IMAP. If you need additional help writing said tool, you may want to ask on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), assuming you have some programming experience already.